# How to keep a Jenkins step 'alive' with declarative pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My use case is the following: I have a web application written in Node, and I've done a set of functional tests with Java and Selenium. I have configured a job in Jenkins using the new declarative pipelines syntax.

Here are the contents of the Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'node:8.2.0') {
          sh 'echo $PATH'
          sh 'npm -v'
          sh 'node -v'

          dir('src/webapp') {
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'nohup npm start &> todomvc.out &'
          }

          sh './gradlew clean test'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Clean up') {
      steps {
        deleteDir()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, first I launch the webapp using npm start and I send it to the background (in order to continue to the next step which is the actual testing).

However when the tests run the webapp isn't available, making them fail.

I've tried replacing:

```
sh 'nohup npm start &> todomvc.out &'
```

with:

```
npm start
```

and when I go to the port I've specified there is an instance of the webapp as expected. However, this blocks the next steps.

What I want is to launch an instance of the webapp and *then* test it with `./gradlew clean test`.

Comment: Try to use parallel stages to keep in running.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587521/how-to-keep-process-running-after-the-stage-is-finished-for-declarative-jenkins?rq=1