# how to keep process running after the stage is finished for declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

```html
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
   stage('Server') {
      agent{
          node {
            label "xxx"
            customWorkspace "/home/xxx/server"
          }
        }
      
      steps {
        sh 'node server.js &'
        //start server
      }
    }
   stage('RunCase') {
      agent{
          node {
            label 'clientServer'
            customWorkspace "/home/xxx/CITest"
          }
        }

      steps{
        sh 'start test'
        sh  'run case here'
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I create above Jenkins pipeline. What I want to do is:
1. start server at server node.
2. start test at test node.

However, I found the server process will be closed when second stage start.
So how to keep server start until my second stage testing work is finished. I try to use `&`, still not working. It seems it will kill all process I started at first stage.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to try to start the two stages in "parallel"-mode. For more informations see this two files: [parallel-declarative-blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) [jenkins-pipeline-syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/). But be carefull, because it is not ensured, that the first stage starts before the second one starts. Maybe you need a waiting time for your tests. Here is an example Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('Run Tests') {
        parallel {
            stage('Start Server') {
                steps {
                    sh 'node server.js &'
                }
            }
            stage('Run Tests) {
                steps {
                    sh  'run case here'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Another solution would be to start the node server in the background. For this you can try different tools, like [nohup](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/nohup/) or [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).